# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string; with SQLCommand.CommandText and SQLCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlconnection, sqlcommand

I'm trying to insert data into my SQL Server 2014 database. I wrote the SQL query with the `@parameters` and used the `SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue` to parse the values, without worrying about SQL injection.

The problem is, when I start the program, I get this exception:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

```
using (SqlCommand insertCall = new SqlCommand())
{
    insertCall.Connection = connection;
    insertCall.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    insertCall.CommandText = "INSERT into CallingHistory  (historyid, callid, duration," +
                               "[time-start],[time-answered],[time-end],[reason-terminated],[from-no],[to-no],[from-dn],[to-dn],[dial-no]," +
                               "[reason-changed],[final-number],[final-dn],[bill-code],[bill-rate],[bill-cost],[bill-name],chain,[from-type]," +
                               "[to-type],[final-type],[from-displayname],[to-dispname],[final-dispname], [missed-queue]) " +
                               "VALUES('@historyid', '@callid', '@duration', '@timestart', '@timeanswered', '@timeend', '@reasonterminated', '@fromno', '@tono', '@fromdn', '@todn'," +
                               "'@dialno', '@reasonchanged', '@finalnumber','@finaldn', '@billcode', '@billrate', @billcost, '@billname', '@chain', '@fromtype', '@totype', '@finaltype'," +
                               "'@fromdisplayname', '@todispname', '@finaldispname', '@missedqueue')";

    string billcost = (values[17] == "" ? "0" : values[17]);
    string timeanswered = (values[4] == "" ? DBNull.Value.ToString() : values[4]);
    string duration = (values[2] == "" ? DBNull.Value.ToString() : values[2]);

     insertCall.Parameters.AddWithValue("@historyid", values[0]);
     insertCall.Parameters.AddWithValue("@callid", values[1]);
     insertCall.Parameters.AddWithValue("@duration", duration);
     insertCall.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timestart", values[3]);
     insertCall.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timeanswered", timeanswered);
     insertCall.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timeend", values[5]);
     insertCall.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reasonterminated", values[6]);
     insertCall.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fromno", values[7]);
     insertCall.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tono", values[8]);
     insertCall.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fromdn", values[9]);
     insertCall.Parameters.AddWithValue("@todn", values[10]);
     insertCall.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dialno", values[11]);
     insertCall.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reasonchanged", values[12]);
     insertCall.Parameters.AddWithValue("@finalnumber", values[13]);
     insertCall.Parameters.AddWithValue("@finaldn", values[14]);
     insertCall.Parameters.AddWithValue("@billcode", values[15]);
     insertCall.Parameters.AddWithValue("@billrate", values[16]);
     insertCall.Parameters.AddWithValue("@billcost", billcost);
     insertCall.Parameters.AddWithValue("@billname", values[18]);
     insertCall.Parameters.AddWithValue("@chain", values[19]);
     insertCall.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fromtype", values[20]);
     insertCall.Parameters.AddWithValue("@totype", values[21]);
     insertCall.Parameters.AddWithValue("@finaltype", values[22]);
     insertCall.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fromdisplayname", values[23]);
     insertCall.Parameters.AddWithValue("@todispname", values[24]);
     insertCall.Parameters.AddWithValue("@finaldispname", values[25]);
     insertCall.Parameters.AddWithValue("@missedqueue", values[26]);

    string sqlquery=insertCall.CommandText;

    foreach (SqlParameter item in insertCall.Parameters)
    {
        sqlquery= sqlquery.Replace(item.ParameterName, item.Value.ToString());
    }

    try
    {
        insertCall.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (SqlException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error inserting into the database");
    }
}
```

I tried to write the SQL query hardcoded into `SqlCommand.CommandText` (insertCall.CommandText).

I wrote this:

```
string sqlquery = insertCall.CommandText;

foreach (SqlParameter item in insertCall.Parameters)
{
    sqlquery = sqlquery.Replace(item.ParameterName, item.Value.ToString());
}

insertCall.CommandText = sqlquery;

try
{
    insertCall.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (SqlException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error inserting into the database");
}
```

**insertCall.CommandText = sqlquery;**

This is an example, what is in insertCall.CommandText

```
INSERT into CallingHistory  (historyid, callid, duration,[time-start],[time-answered],[time-end],[reason-terminated],[from-no],[to-no],[from-dn],[to-dn],[dial-no],[reason-changed],[final-number],[final-dn],[bill-code],[bill-rate],[bill-cost],[bill-name],chain,[from-type],[to-type],[final-type],[from-displayname],[to-dispname],[final-dispname], [missed-queue])
VALUES('Call 29273', '00000C0F29FCCCBC_82', '','2021.03.03 18:07:56','','2021.03.03 18:07:58','Failed','Ext.54','012345678','54','012345678','012345678','','','','','',0,'','','Extension','LineSet','','M Ulus','012345678','', '\r\n')
```

When this is in the `insertCall.CommandText` the query is successful, and the program successfully inserts data into the database.

I also tried with converting with `DateTime.Parse`, but it still doesn't work.

```
insertCall.Parameters.AddWithValue("@duration", DateTime.Parse(duration).TimeOfDay);
insertCall.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timestart", DateTime.Parse(values[3]));
insertCall.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timeanswered", DateTime.Parse(timeanswered));
insertCall.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timeend", DateTime.Parse(values[5]));
```

I tried everything I could think of.

Do you guys have any ideas, what the problem is or what the work around is. I really would like it to be protective against SQL injection.

And on the other hand I heard, that the error could be because of SQL Server 2014. That we need to update it. I will try it out on SQL Server 2019 tomorrow.

[Here are the columns of the table I'm trying to insert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5W4Ux.png)

Comment: [Don't use `.AddWithValue`](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/), use the correct types (as in, the actual types of the columns, which need not be the same as the types you're using client-side). When you have that, you can start troubleshooting conversion issues you may have on the client side (for instance, you never use `DBNull.Value.ToString()` to insert `NULL` as that's just the empty string; use something like `(object) value ?? DBNull.Value`).

Comment: And **DO NOT** put your parameters in the `VALUES` clause into single quotes - don't do `VALUES('@historyid',`- use `VALUES(@historyid, ` instead - single quotes signify **string literals** - so right now you're trying to insert all your parameters as **string literals** into the columns ....

Comment: Fire up SQL Server Profiler. In the events section ensure that all "Start" events for query and batch execution are enabled. (Since your query causes an error "complete" events will not fire). Run your program to capture the actual query being sent to SQL Server. You can then debug it in SSMS.

Comment: @jeroen I wouldn't be so bothered about AddWithValue for an insert values  query,.

Comment: Change your "working" query to this: `&VALUES('Call 29273', '00000C0F29FCCCBC_82', '','@timestart', ...` - it'll begin to fail in the same way because the string `@timestart` cannot be parsed to a datetime. If you don't see why it's not working, consider that your sql is equivalent to c# like `Person p = new Person(); p.Name = "John"; MessageBox.Show("p.Name")` - the MessageBox shows literally "p.Name", not "John" . Follow marc_s' advice